# 3 radio buttons that produces random values on textbox, but only reads 1 value when submitted

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

[User interface with explanations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMB2j.png)

I have 3 radio buttons that produce a random value on the control number textbox. My problem is,
when I submit the form, it only reads the "cash load request" radiobutton that starts with the control number "RLR10". Even though the textbox's value is on "AL10". Thank you in advance.

Controller:

```
function ticket(){
        
        //inputs message
        $message    = $this->input->post('message');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("message", "Message", "required");

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
         
          
            $insert = $this->Dashboard_model->insertTicket(
                array(
                    "ticket_id" => $this->input->post("tickets"),
                    "user_id" => $this->session->userdata("user_id"),
                    "account_type" => $this->input->post("accounttype"),
                    "website" => $this->input->post("website"),
                    "MA_name" => $this->session->userdata("user_name"),
                    "username"=> $this->session->userdata("user_username"),
                    "contact" => $this->session->userdata("user_contact"),
                    "message" => $message,
                    "transaction" => $this->input->post("transaction"),
                    "amount" => $this->input->post("amount"),
                    "ticket_date" => date("Y-m-d")
//                     "attachment" => $this->upload()
                )
                
            );  
            
            redirect(base_url('dashboard'));
            
                }
                else 
                {
                    echo 'No';
                }
            }
```

Model:

```
  //Insert the ticket data
        public function insertTicket($data = array())
        {
            $this->db->insert("ticket", $data);

        }
        
        //Login version2
        function control($where = array())
        {
            return $this->db->where($where)->get("ticket")->row();

            
        }
   

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-form" onSubmit="return handleClick()">
     
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="name">Control Number:</label>
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-4" id="textboxes" style="display: none">
        <input type="text" name="tickets" value="" readonly>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4" id="textbox1" style="display: none">
        <input type="text" name="tickets" value="" readonly>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4" id="textbox2" style="display: none">
        <input type="text" name="tickets" value="" readonly/>
        </div>
</div>



<div class="table">
      <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>TRANSACTION TYPE</th>
                 <th>AMOUNT</th>
                 <th>DETAILS</th>
             </tr>
                
             <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="radiobutton" value="Advance Load" disabled>
                <label for="transactiontype">Advance Load</label></td>
                <td rowspan="3"><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                Account Recipient:<input type="name" disabled>
                Reference No:<input type="name" disabled><br>
                Payment Method:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="name" disabled>
                Sender:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="name" disabled>
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" name="transaction" value="Regular Load Request">
                <label for="transactiontype">Regular Load Request</label></td>
             </tr>
  
             <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" name="transaction" value="Cash Load Request">
                <label for="transactiontype">Cash Load Request</label></td>             
                <td>Recieved from:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="name" disabled> Recieved By:&nbsp;<input type="name" disabled></td>              
             </tr>
</table></center>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('input[name="transaction"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Advance Load') {
            $('#textboxes').show();
            

           
            
        }
    
        else {
           
            $('#textboxes').hide();
        }
    });
    
    $('input[name="transaction"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Regular Load Request') {
            $('#textbox1').show();
          
            
        }
    
        else {
            $('#textbox1').hide();
           ;
        }
    });
    
    $('input[name="transaction"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Cash Load Request') {
            $('#textbox2').show();
          
            
        }
    
        else {
            $('#textbox2').hide();
           ;
        }
    });
    
    $('input[name="accounttype"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'VIP') {
            $('#radiobutton').attr("disabled", false);
          
            
        }
    
        else {
            $('#radiobutton').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#radiobutton').attr("checked", false);
            $('#textboxes').hide();
           ;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post final HTML as it appears in the browser and turn that into a [mre]?

Comment: Hello, I did some editing on the html part. I'm beginner so I'm not sure if you're satisfied on what I did. If you need more, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not what I meant. As far as I can tell, your problem is purely client-side, and we cannot run PHP code in a stack snippet. Remove all irrelevant code, and post the final, rendered HTML only, without any `<?php...?>` tags (insert example output instead).

Comment: I edited it again. Please see the screenshot, this is my expected output >>>  https://prnt.sc/w33j10 <<<

Comment: Right, now please remove any irrelevant code. This is about textboxes and radio buttons, so please create a [mre], emphasis on minimal.

Comment: What is `input[name="accounttype"]`? Not contained in your HTML. You are _disabling_ the first radio button in the click handler placed on that, what is the purpose of that?

Comment: I'm trying to build a [mre] here: https://jsfiddle.net/cp7bf19j/ I'm too lazy to do all the debugging myself though, so feel free to fix it so it demonstrates your problem.